# MySQL query yearweek of the current week to start on a Thursday, end on Wednesday

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a `SQL` statement set up to grab data from the current calendar week. By default, this grabs data starting on Sunday and ending on Saturday. I was hoping to change this so that the start of the calendar week is Thursday and it ends on Wednesday. Below is my statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM transactions 
WHERE yearweek(transactionDate) = yearweek(now()) 
ORDER BY transactionDate DESC
```

Is there a way to modify the yearweek in a way to allow this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of [`WEEKDAY()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) which returns a number representing the day of the week (0 = Monday, 6 = Sunday) and some straightforward maths to rewrite this query.

Subtract the weekday you want the week to start on (in your case 4 = Thursday) from the selected date, add 7 and take the remainder from 7. This will give you the number of days to subtract to get the start of your range.

A similar logic applies to calculate the end date of the range.

```
SELECT * 
FROM transactions 
WHERE DATE(transactionDate)
    BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(NOW()) - 4 + 7) % 7 DAY)
        AND DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 6 - (WEEKDAY(NOW()) - 4 + 7) % 7 DAY)
ORDER BY transactionDate DESC;
```

For a different starting date, substitute the weekday for `4` in the query.

Answer (score -4):

You can specify start day - default is 0 (Sunday).

Just set it to 4 (Thursday):

```
YEARWEEK(transactionDate, 4)
```

Comment: It seems when I do this, it simply pulls data from last week starting on Sunday for some reason. Here's what I updated to:

`SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE YEARWEEK(transactionDate, 4) = YEARWEEK(NOW()) ORDER BY transactionDate DESC`

Comment: 'Mode' flag in YEARWEEK and WEEK functions does not mean a day of week. See official docs for details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week