# I m try to get the weeknum for a week starting on Thursday with the input given as date

Tags: mysql

```
Select week('2017-08-03')
```

it gives me 31 as week number but it should be 32.

By googling I tried

```
select week('2017-08-03',4)
```

still I only get 31.

Here based on the input date given i'm trying to get the week number considering week starts on Thursday and end on Wednesday.

Any help in this is much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week), the `mode` argument to `WEEK` specifies whether the week starts on Sunday or Monday, and how weeks are counted. There's no option to start on Thursday. Here are the meanings of each value:

[image]

So `4` means that the week starts on Sunday, week numbers start at `0`, and week `1` is the first week with 4 or more days in the year.

See [MySQL query yearweek of the current week to start on a Thursday, end on Wednesday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650603/mysql-query-yearweek-of-the-current-week-to-start-on-a-thursday-end-on-wednesda) for how to do what you want.